# How to run security updates automatically in new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm having auto-scaling group in AWS from where I start new ECS (Amazon ECS-optimized Linux) instances. I'm wondering if could apply latest security updates automatically during instance launch?

So in practice can I run "sudo yum update --security" automatically at startup? I've tried to place that command under "User Data" but without real success.

Or is it preferred way that I do this manually periodically and build new AMI?

Comment: Of course this depends your application needs. Installing security updates at startup can increase the time needed for autoscaling. It would not be a bad idea to build an image with latest updates already installed. A software like Packer can help you automate the process of building an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working in user data because this is a interactive command. Use below command in user data and it will work.

```
sudo yum update --security -y
```

Comment: Userdata runs as root, no need for sudo